# App runs perfectly in simulator but I get "Undefined Symbols" error when running on iPod Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app runs fine in the simulator, but I get the 
`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:` errors when I run it on my device. I have all my certificates, provisioning profiles, etc. set up properly as I am able to launch other apps from Xcode on my iPod Touch. The iPod touch is 3rd generation running iOS5.1. Here are the errors specifically:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_decomp in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_comp in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_dtor in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_init in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_dtor in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_init in NMSSH(comp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As you can see, I'm using the NMSSH framework.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
~Carpetfizz

EDIT: Just threw in `libz.1.2.5.dylib` and everything works perfectly!

Comment: FYI - You are not getting these errors when running the app. These are linker errors that happen near the end of building your app.

Comment: You can check out the answer from [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286150/linker-errors-when-trying-to-install-new-google-analytics-3-0-beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try including a libz. May be it will help in getting these runtime linker errors go away. or you need to specify the linker flag in build settings.

Comment: Thanks, I already have a libz actually. How do I specify a linker flag, and what does it do? Btw, here is a screenshot of all my links:http://i.imgur.com/yiqgDwP.png

Comment: Marked your answer as correct because I just randomly included another libz and it worked. An explanation of why would be great.

Comment: I had this problem in my unit tests, and same answer worked for me.  just had to add libz.dylib to my Test Target