# Linker errors when trying to install new Google Analytics 3.0 Beta

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I believe just today Google released a new update to their iOS Analytics frame work (version 3.0). When I follow the instructions and try to run the code, I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_inflate", referenced
>   from:
>         l002 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)   "_deflate", referenced from:
>         l001 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)   "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         l002 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)   "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
>         l001 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGAdvertiserId.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGAdvertisingTrackingEnabledMacro.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGMobileAdwordsUniqueIdMacro.o)
>   "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
>         l002 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
>         l027 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
>         l002 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
>         l027 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
>         l002 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)
>         l003 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)   "*deflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         l001 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(NSData+zlib.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
>         l027 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
>         l002 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
>         l027 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
>         l003 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Possible they forgot to include a lib I need to add? (some other aspects of the instructions they forgot to change as well). Otherwise have followed their instructions to a tee and still not getting the needed results.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I had to add both `libz.dylib` and `AdSupport.framework` to the build phases to make this go away. Google doesn't include these in their instructions so going to check with them to make sure this is OK then will update this post.

UPDATE: Now you also need to add `libsqlite3.0.dylib` to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks! Google now lists `libz.dylib` in their [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/), but `AdSupport.framework` is still missing.

Comment: @StephSharp - Yeah I asked the guy about it in the Google forum, and I don't think he acknowledged it really. Ah well, I just know it works when you include AdSupport.framework.

Comment: What a shame - you cannot install analytics without using Ad framework. Thanks for a tip.

Comment: Great thanks, really the solution, that made me happy after two hours of headache when updating adMob library due to new API policy (UDID stuff)

Comment: thank you, it works! "AdSupport.frame" is still missing until now. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

Comment: 4 months and counting ... Google still can't be bothered to add one (critical) line to their install instructions. Huh?

Comment: Any ideas what to do now that Apple is rejecting apps that include AdSupport framework without displaying ads?

Comment: In my case I did not have to add libsqlite3.0.dylib. No sure if it is really needed.

Comment: thanks a lot. You saved my JOB i just forgot to add libz.tdb

Comment: Thanks for this. Also don't forget to link the 'libGoogleAnalytics.a" in your project settings > build phases > link Binary With Libraries which you can find under Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Frameworks

Answer (score 24):

I downloaded version 3.06 of the Google Analytics Services for iOS in early April 2014, and STILL ran into the problems referenced above. Google *has* updated their docs to mention the need to link the libz.dylib and the AdSupport.framework. 
SOLUTION: I found through trial and error, I also needed to link the **libsqlite3.dylib** in order to build on the simulator or to a device.

Comment: In one project I could build w/o having to do this. In another project I had to do this to make it compile.

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me, thanks. I am also using the HockeyApp SDK if that has any bearing. I had already added the libz.dylib and AdSupport.framework and that didn't help. Adding the libsqlite3.dylib did the trick though!

Answer (score 22):

Add

`libz.dylib`

`AdSupport.framework`

`libsqlite3.0.dylib`

Google did not update their guide as of 8 Oct 2013.

Google Analytics Guide is [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/)

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed.

Comment: Added the needed libraries mentioned above and I am still receiving 6 link errors. Any ideas?

Comment: way to be productive there @MaxMommersteeg

Comment: It works! If you hadn't posted this, I would have properly tried to fix it the hole night. Thank you!

Comment: I had this issue when adding Google Sign In, needed to add `libz.tbd` in Xcode 7. This was after adding the `-ObjC` linker flag which is also undocumented...

Answer (score 10):

None of the above solutions worked for me. What did work for me, however, was adding these:

```
libz.dylib

libsqlite3.0.dylib

libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```

The libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a is a file that can be found in the download for Google Analytics for Mobile Apps iOS SDK v3.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for this. Nothing worked until I downloaded libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Answer (score 1):

I had `libz.dylib` and `AdSupport.framework` as per instruction from Google, it worked fine.

Then I had to add `-all_load` in other linker flags for some other library dependency, then google analytics started failing build with linker error.

I had to add `libsqlite3.0.dylib` framework to get it to work.

So there is something to do with `-all_load` linker flag

Answer (score 1):

Till third party developers do not enable `BITCODE` for their old libraries, you can disable bit code in your own project if you are not going to have a Apple Watch extension for you application.

[image]