# Google + integration in xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.2

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
      -[TAGNetReachability start] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
      -[TAGNetReachability start] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
      -[TAGNetReachability start] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)
      -[TAGNetReachability stop] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
      -[TAGNetReachability stop] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGNetReachability.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore selectStmtWithTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore hasValidPropertyColumns] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore errorMessage] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl tablePresent:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore removeStatementForQuery:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore finalizeAndClearStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore prepareSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore executeSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl openDatabaseAndInitStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore prepareSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore dropTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore dropTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore executeSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I follow this link [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_1_creating_the_console_name_project) and also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286150/linker-errors-when-trying-to-install-new-google-analytics-3-0-beta) and I tried some methods but cant resolve the above errors.

Answer (score 2):

you need to import the support file of `SystemConfiguration.framework`, `libsqlite3.0.tbd`, `libsqlite3.tbd` and `libz.tbd` from frameworks and your errors will disappear.

Comment: Yes I added SystemConfiguration.framework but others not available in xcode7.2 what to do for this

Comment: Thank you ll check and tell you

Comment: no it not working. I already tried this not working. Now I do from initial from starting throw this error even added those libraries

Comment: framework not found GoogleOpenSource
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: can you upadte your question

Comment: Google+ sdk was depreceated so need to user GoogleSignin sdk. Now its working.

Comment: @TamilKing - happy to hear bro, if my answer is useful please accept

Comment: I upvote your answer for your kind response. Bt solution is differ.

Comment: I only needed to add libsqlite3.tbd. Thanks for the help.